# Автоопределение кодировки текста

Tags: кодировка, php

Беда на мою голову. Получаю ответ от серверов, и они отдают ее в разной кодировке. А мне нужно сохранить ее в utf 8. В общем, для одного нормально так: `iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $str)`, а для другого так: `iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $str)`.

Вот как определить, в какой кодировке пришел ответ?

Пробовал `mb_detect_encoding($str)` и `mb_detect_encoding($str, "CP1251, CP1252"`), но не помогает. В первом случае ответ UTF-8, во втором - Windows-1251.

Comment: @wwwplaton, попробуйте использовать класс [forceutf8][1]. Обсуждение похожей проблемы и вышеуказанного класса [вот тут][2]

   [1]:https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8
   [2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: Не разобрался :( Думаю, нужно что-то попроще.

Comment: в ответе нет заголовка с кодировкой? или этому значению нельзя доверять?

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой задачей, у меня работало так:

```
@$str_cp1251 = iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', $html);
$kod1 = preg_match('#.#u', $html);
$kod2 = preg_match('#.#u', $str_cp1251);
if ($kod1 == 0) { // если $kod1 равен нулю то это 1251, конверируем
    $html = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $html);
}
else {
   // если $kod1 не равен нулю то это UTF-8
}
```